# How to access admin menu on a lexmark printer with cartridge error

Tags: printer

I have a lexmark ms517dn and it needs a cartridge replacement. My problem is that i have no cartridge now and need to configure the printer, but the menu is not accessible. Is there a key shortcut or a code to enter in the menu?

PS I don't have a LAN connection available

Answer (score 0):

I would run an IP scan to find out what the IP address is. [www.advanced-ip-scanner.com](http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com) is what I usually use, because it does not need to be installed.

Open the ip in your browser (can be done from the scanner) and you can configure the printer from there.

Comment: i'm looking for another option, it has no lan connected now

Comment: You should've added that to your post.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple process to activate the unsupported Lexmark cartridge override: Hold down the green button* and the cancel (X) button simultaneously. Upon activating the override, the error message will go away and the printer will do a semi-reboot. After the reboot you will be able to resume your printing.